Issues with Firebase Dependancies:
When updating a previously made app to capacitor 6.0, attempting to build in android studio leads to this error message:
FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(false).addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), instanceIdResult -> {
                                                                                            ^
  class file for androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity not found

The code block in question that the error points to is this.
            JSObject data = new JSObject();
            data.put("token", instanceIdResult.getToken());
            call.resolve(data);

Looking at the app dependancies, I had noticed that the dependancies that were alleged to be missing exist,     implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
I attempted to update these dependancies, but there isn't a firebase dependancy that I noticed. These updates did not cause the project to build properly.

Ionic provides a document to assist with updating to capacitor 6. Make sure to follow all android steps: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/6-0#upgrade-android-studio

That fixed the issue it seems, Now I've got some new errors I may be able to figure out with other. questions on this site.
